# Restricting keys to specific part of the document

Tags: xslt

I need to restrict the nodes of keys to a specific part of the document. I think it is easier to explain with an example.

Here ist my XML

```
<xmlinterface>
<invoices>
    <invoice>
        <total>150</total>
        <positions>
            <position><status>valid</status><taxid>1</taxid></position>
            <position><status>invalid</status><taxid>2</taxid></position>
        </positions>
        <taxes>
            <taxe><taxid>1</taxid><amount>10</amount></taxe>
            <taxe><taxid>2</taxid><amount>20</amount></taxe>
        </taxes>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <total>250</total>
        <positions>
           <position><status>valid</status><taxid>1</taxid></position>
        </positions>
        <taxes>
            <taxe><taxid>1</taxid><amount>5</amount></taxe>
        </taxes>
    </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Here ist my XSLT

```
 <xsl:key name="kTaxes" match="taxe" use="taxid"/>

<xsl:template match="xmlinterface" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ArrayList>
        <xsl:for-each select="./invoices/invoice">
               <invoice>
               <total><xsl:value-of select="./total"/></total>
               <total_without_taxe>
               <xsl:value-of select="./total - sum(key('kTaxes',positions/position[status!='invalid']/taxid)/amount[normalize-space() != ''])"/>
               </total_without_taxe>
               </invoice>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ArrayList>
</xsl:template>
```

And here is my generated output

```
    <invoice>
    <total>150</total>
    <total_without_taxe>135</total_without_taxe>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <total>250</total>
    <total_without_taxe>235</total_without_taxe>
</invoice>
```

And that is the desired result

```
    <invoice>
    <total>150</total>
    <total_without_taxe>140</total_without_taxe>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <total>250</total>
    <total_without_taxe>245</total_without_taxe>
</invoice>
```

I want that only taxes with at least one "valid" position should be subtracted from the "total" value. Taxes and positions are joind with the taxid attribute. With my actual xslt i have the problem that also taxes from other invoices are concerned.

Is there a possibility to limit the nodes of the keys to the actual invoice Element? Or is there another way to do it right?

Here is a more "complicated" example:

```
<xmlinterface>
<invoices>
    <invoice>
        <total>150</total>
        <positions>
            <position><status>valid</status><taxid>1</taxid></position>
            <position><status>valid</status><taxid>1</taxid></position>
            <position><status>invalid</status><taxid>2</taxid></position>
            <position><status>valid</status><taxid>2</taxid></position>
        </positions>
        <taxes>
            <taxe><taxid>1</taxid><amount>10</amount></taxe>
            <taxe><taxid>2</taxid><amount>20</amount></taxe>
        </taxes>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <total>250</total>
        <positions>
           <position><status>valid</status><taxid>1</taxid></position>
        </positions>
        <taxes>
            <taxe><taxid>1</taxid><amount>5</amount></taxe>
        </taxes>
    </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Here is the desired result

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayList>
<invoice>
<total>150</total>
<total_without_taxe>120</total_without_taxe>
</invoice>
<invoice>
<total>250</total>
<total_without_taxe>245</total_without_taxe>
</invoice>
</ArrayList>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you need a key here.

Comment: I do not know how should it go otherwise ...
I am grateful for any other solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to restrict the nodes of keys to a specific part of the
>   document.

This is possible if you use **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kTaxes" match="taxe" use="taxid"/>

<xsl:template match="xmlinterface">
    <ArrayList>
        <xsl:for-each select="invoices/invoice">
            <invoice>
                <xsl:copy-of select="total"/>
                <total_without_taxe>
                    <xsl:value-of select="total - sum(key('kTaxes', positions/position[status!='invalid']/taxid, .)/amount)"/>
               </total_without_taxe>
            </invoice>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ArrayList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 1.0, you need to concatenate the id of the context node to the key value <strike>as shown in the answer by Rudolf Yurgenson.</strike>

Or do it without using a key at all:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="xmlinterface">
    <ArrayList>
        <xsl:for-each select="invoices/invoice">
            <invoice>
                <xsl:copy-of select="total"/>
                <total_without_taxe>
                    <xsl:value-of select="total - sum(taxes/taxe[taxid=current()/positions/position[status!='invalid']/taxid]/amount)"/>
               </total_without_taxe>
            </invoice>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ArrayList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 Version without using a key not work. Because it is possible that there is another valid position with the same taxid. And then the taxe is used twice.

Comment: @tomas I don't think so. Can you post an example input where this would happen?

Comment: <positions>
    <position><status>valid</status><taxid>1</taxid></position>
    <position><status>valid</status><taxid>2</taxid></position>
    <position><status>invalid</status><taxid>2</taxid></position>
   </positions>

Comment: You have to replace the <positions> element of the first invoice in my inital example.

Comment: @tomas Is the result shown here correct? If not, why not? http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2E

Comment: Sorry, you have right. It works also with your XSLT 1.0 Version without key. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility to limit the nodes of the keys to the actual invoice Element?

This can easily be done through `generate-id()`. Here we index `<taxe>` elements by the ID of their `<invoice>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="kValidTaxes" match="taxe[
        taxid = ancestor::invoice//position[status = 'valid']/taxid
        and amount &gt; 0
    ]" use="generate-id(ancestor::invoice)" />

    <xsl:template match="invoices">
        <ArrayList>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice" />
        </ArrayList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="invoice">
        <xsl:variable name="taxes" select="key('kValidTaxes', generate-id())" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="total" />
            <total_without_taxe>
                <xsl:value-of select="total - sum($taxes/amount)" />
            </total_without_taxe>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that the `<xsl:key>` match expression can be limited to the valid taxes only. The `<taxid>` is no longer important after that, the ID of the enclosing `<invoice>` is enough to reference the correct set of taxes.

Comment: IMHO, your approach eliminates the reason for using the key in the first place. All the "keying" work is done by the match expression, and all that the key does is point right back to the context node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the objection. An `<xsl:key>` points to a set of nodes, given a string. In this case the string is the ID of the invoice, and the assiciated set of nodes is all the valid `<taxe>` elements for that invoice. That looks like a perfectly valid way to use a key to me.

Comment: My point is that the filtering of which `taxe` nodes are valid is not done by keying, but by the match pattern. If you use the same match pattern in a template, and apply that template from the context of invoice, you will get the same result. The only filtering done by the actual keying process is which invoice to consider. We are already in the context of that invoice.

Comment: Right, the filtering is done by the match pattern, i.e. only nodes that fit the pattern are considered. Thats the whole point of a match pattern, after all. I do realize that I could use the same predicate in a template, but I don't want to. The reason for me to use a key here is the ability to abstract away what "valid taxes" are, so that I no longer have to care and can I write `key('kValidTaxes', ...)` in my template. It works well with the "I need the valid taxes for this invoice" semantics and therefore makes the template easier to read (and it makes selecting the valid taxes re-usable).

Comment: "*The reason for me to use a key here is the ability to abstract away what "valid taxes" are*" That is the part that I find troublesome. Yes, the match pattern in the key does that; No, that's not a good reason to use a key here.

Comment: I'm sorry, but still fail to see why. Especially I fail to see why that usage would be "troublesome". What kind of potential pitfalls are there?

Comment: No pitfalls, just an unnecessary complication.Please compare your solution to my (the XSLT 1.0 one). The expression used to filter the taxe nodes is exactly the same. But it is done in the current context. What is the advantage of adding a key that says: "go out of the context of the current invoice and establish a new context of ... ehm... this very invoice"?

Comment: The advantage is twofold: A) I don't have a bunch of XPath sitting around in a predicate that has no semantic value attached to it. Of course doing the filtering inline selects the right nodes, too. But using `key('kValidTaxes', ...)` makes it way easier to reason about what the template does, which is something I generally find very desirable. B) It makes the whole thing reusable without copy/pasting a comparatively unwieldy XPath expression, another nice trait. In the end it's comparable to "writing a one-liner function" vs. "inlining the computation". I would always favor the function.

Comment: @michael Your objection went from "I find this troublesome" to "ok, not troublesome, but unnecessarily complex" to "nitpicking" to "never mind, I'll just walk away" pretty quickly. I'm willing to learn, but I'm still missing the substance in your argument.

Comment: I did not mean to prick (I do believe I stayed calm and objective all the time). I actually want to understand what's wrong with my code — I am far from perfect when it comes to XSLT, and I'm open to criticism. I tried to lay out my reasoning against "simply inlining it", since I have thought about it and actively decided against it, based on that thought process. So if my thought process is wrong, I want to correct it. "There is a way to do it in fewer lines" just isn't compelling enough a reason for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything new to add.

Comment: Well, arguing against the two main points that I brought forward (abstraction and re-usability) would have been productive, that's what I was after. But okay, let's leave it at that.

Comment: I completely agree with the benefits of abstraction and reusability. Even when performance is considered, using a key more than once can increase performance many times. Good job Tomalak, and +1 from me. I think that people can only benefit if they try to learn new concepts and techniques and break beyond the bounds of their limited vision. This is what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

Version of xslt is not specified in your question, so I'd suggest that you use XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="kTaxes" match="taxe" use="concat(taxid, '_', generate-id(ancestor::invoice))"/>

<xsl:template match="xmlinterface" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ArrayList>
        <xsl:for-each select="./invoices/invoice">
               <invoice>
               <total><xsl:value-of select="./total"/></total>
               <total_without_taxe>
               <xsl:value-of select="./total - sum(key('kTaxes',concat(positions/position[status!='invalid']/taxid, '_', generate-id(.)))/amount[normalize-space() != ''])"/>
               </total_without_taxe>
               </invoice>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ArrayList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we use a compound key that depends on both invoice and taxid. In XSLT 2.0 it's possible to specify the third argument in 'key' function that defines that subtree where this function is applied, i.e. key('kTaxes',positions/position[status!='invalid']/taxid, .) in your case

Comment: Upon reread, this is not going to work if there are multiple positions that meet the criteria. You cannot use a node-set as an argument in `concatenate()`; only the value of the first node will be considered.

Comment: I have put a more complicated example in my question. And you have right the solution with concat does not work. So i will use your solution "XSLT 1.0 without keys".

Comment: My idea was to show how to do the following: 'Restricting keys to specific part of the document' in different versions of XSLT using author's template.